# Schedule a job to run at a given time on Parse

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to schedule a job to run at a certain time in Parse? For example, I have a calendar app and I want to remind users they have something on in say 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is called "Background Jobs" and is a part of `Cloud Code`.

See guide here: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-advanced-background-jobs

Comment: ic, so its impossible to say schedule something programatically? Like say I want to do something at time time where time is given by user. I guess I could need a "workaround" by having a Jobs table and a background job will query this table periodically to pick out tasks to do?

Comment: No, AFAIK there is no way to do this, so your workaround is probably your best bet. Just be careful so the job doesn't get too much work to do so it hits the time limit.